# the version of tomcat-util

Tags: java, tomcat

I am following an example to use a class inside tomcat-util. From Maven, I can find the version is 5.5.23, looks like the version is changing when Tomcat changes.

However I cannot find version 6 which is my tomcat uses. Anyone is familiar with this package?

Comment: `tomcat-util.jar` is part of the standard Tomcat distribution.  You should not need to retrieve a copy from Maven.

Comment: if he's *following an example* I guess there is some use case for that jar outside of tomcat internals...

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting issue.

It appears that `tomcat-util.jar` is only available in Tomcat 5 and Tomcat 7.

In Tomcat 6 classes from `tomcat-util.jar` seem to be present in `tomcat-coyote.jar`. So you might try referencing it for your Tomcat 6 example.